# Python regexp find exact word

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove certain special characters and some junk like '&quot' from my words (but I want to keep some special characters like 'é','á', etc.). How can I match the EXACT pattern '&quot' (or 'quot', since I can remove '&' separately)?

```
word = re.sub('[,|;|?|!|(|)|{|}|.|&|\bquot\b]+', '', word)
```

I'm tring this, but it removes all 'q''u''o''t' characters.

**EDIT**
Test strings as requested:

```
'&quottermészet&quot' should be 'természet'    
'data,' should be 'data'
```

Comment: Provide test strings and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

When inside square brackets, you don't need the **|** separator

Try with this regex

```
re.sub(r'[,;?!(){}.]|\&quot', '', word)
```

Comment: I'd use `re.sub(r'[,;?!(){}.]+|&quot', '', word)`, no need to match and replace empty strings.

Comment: Yes, avoiding to match empty strings is good. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
re.sub('&quot', '', "abc&quotdef")
```

Comment: Well, yeah, but I wonder how you can add this to the whole `'[,|;|?|!|(|)|{|}|.]+'`
 expression.